# Increment field of mysql database using codeigniter's active record syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have the following php-codeigniter script which attempts to increment a field of a record using active-record syntax:

```
$data = array('votes' => '(votes + 1)');
$this->db->where('id', $post['identifier']);
$this->db->update('users', $data);
```

This produces the following SQL:

`"UPDATE`users`SET`votes`= '(votes + 1)' WHERE`id`= '44'`"

Which doesn't run, but this SQL does do what I'm looking for:
`"UPDATE`users`SET`votes`= (votes + 1) WHERE`id`= '44'`"` <--Note the lack of quotes around (votes + 1)

Does anyone know how to implement this type of query with codeigniter's active record syntax?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You can do as given below:

```
$this->db->where('id', $post['identifier']);
$this->db->set('votes', 'votes+1', FALSE);
$this->db->update('users');
```

The reason this works is because the third (optional) FALSE parameter tells CodeIgniter not to protect the generated query with backticks (`'`). This means that the generated SQL will be:
`UPDATE users SET votes= votes + 1 WHERE id= '44'`
If you notice, the backticks are removed from `'(votes+1)'`, which produces the desired effect of incrementing the votes attribute by 1.

Answer (score 4):

```
$data = array('votes' => 'votes + 1');

foreach ($data as $key=>$val) {
    $this->db->set($key, $val, FALSE);
}

$this->db->where('id', $post['identifier']);
$this->db->update('users', $data);
```

Comment: You don't need the entire $data array again in the update clause. You need just parts that should still be escaped when running the query. So in essence you may want to have it as : ```$this->db->update('users', ['some_key'=>'some value']); ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as given below:

```
    public function increment_product_count(){
        $product_id=$this->input->post('product_id');
        $this->db->where('id', $product_id);
        $this->db->set('click_count', 'click_count+1', FALSE);
        $this->db->update('tbl_product');
    }
```