# CodeIgniter Active Record +1

Tags: php, codeigniter, active-record-query

how i can do that query:

```
UPDATE `xxx` SET `xx`=xx+1
```

with Active Record in Codeigniter ?

Thanks for your help ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increment field of mysql database using codeigniter's active record syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373564/increment-field-of-mysql-database-using-codeigniters-active-record-syntax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->db->where('id', 'yourid');
$this->db->set('xx', '`xx`+1', FALSE);
$this->db->update('xxx');
```

Note the third parameter in the `set` function.

This function tells CodeIgniter not to add a backtick (`) on the field.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following code:

```
//$this->db->where('id', 'yourid');
$this->db->set('xx', 'xx+1',FALSE);
$this->db->update('xxx');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$this->db->where('id',$id);
$this->db->update('xxx',array('xx',$xx+1));
```