# Query not working, when I try to increment existing record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter.

Trying to use query (I got this by using `get_compiled_update('invoice')`)

```
UPDATE `invoice` SET `paid` = 'paid + 100' WHERE `invoice_id` = '46'
```

but it is not working, saying

```
0 rows affected
```

In my model

```
 $this->db
            ->where('invoice_id',$invoice_id)
            ->set('paid',"paid + ".$payment_price)
            ->update('invoice');
```

What should I do to make it work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373564/increment-field-of-mysql-database-using-codeigniters-active-record-syntax

Comment: set('paid','paid + '.$payment_price,false)