# Update query increment field plus 1 codeigniter function

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i want to increment my field value to its current value plus 1 in my codeigniter project. so, i made one function but it is not working. my function is.

```
function increse_field_by_1($table_name,$fieldToIncrease,$whileCondition){

$this->db->where($whileCondition);
$this->db->set($fieldToIncrease, $fieldToIncrease+1, FALSE);
$this->db->update($table_name); 
$query = $this->db->get();

}
```

and its displaying error like.

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column '$fieldToIncrease' in 'field list'

UPDATE `rule` SET ruleid = $fieldToIncrease+1 WHERE `interface` = 'lan'
```

i don't know how to resolve it. please help me.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373564/increment-field-of-mysql-database-using-codeigniters-active-record-syntax

Comment: how and where do you call increse_field_by_1 ? - show this type of code pls

Answer (score 2):

you tried to increment the value in php
try this instead

```
function increse_field_by_1($table_name,$fieldToIncrease,$whileCondition){

    $this->db->where($whileCondition);
    $this->db->set($fieldToIncrease, $fieldToIncrease."+1", FALSE);
    $this->db->update($table_name); 
}
```

Your `$this->db->get()` call isn't needed because update does the job already.
Just remove this line.

For more information take a look [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=update#updating-data)

Comment: Error Number: 1096

No tables used

SELECT *

Comment: yeah that's because db->get isn't necessary - i updated my post

Comment: How can i do it with `update_batch()` multiple records have different value to increment?

Comment: i don't think you can - you should iterate over for yourself and do the updates manually